# How to perform regression using a 2-D matrix to predict a single constant value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

How do I predict a single target value with size of [1 x 1] using input of size [M x N]?

I worked with data where every row of features had a corresponding 'target' value I'm trying to match with my prediction, so dimensions of input and output are matched.

I could duplicate the single 'target' value M times to create a target with [M x 1] size, but I think theoretically, using a single row of features to predict a single target (albeit the target is constant), then tuning the model over many rows (iterations) for the final model, is not the same as using multiple rows and multiple columns to predict the single target value. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think it would not work out pretty well, since your model'd most likely just learn to project every input to the constant output. So no real learning will occur. What's your point in trying to predict a constant value? If you want to predict different target values you'd definitely need a variety of target values to train your model.

Comment: that was my challenge. im tying to get a 'score' prediction. an analogy would be if each row is a single transaction of a home sale, with feats such as 'time to close transaction', 'customer rating', 'home value' etc, and trying to predict a known "Monthly Salesman Ranking Score" using all of that data.

Comment: Sounds like a nice challenge but you'll definitely need data where you have 'real' targets instead of one constant value. Your model can just learn information that's within your dataset and if you only have one constant target, it won't have enough information to predict other values as well with a good accuracy.

Comment: thanks for the input!